# Why wont my input fields validate through javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a select tag, and 2 input fields. I want to validate the input fields, but every time i press the button "Godkend", it does not validate, it does not even read the javascript function. Why is this happining?

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3"> 
            <div class="input-holder">
                <select name="rest_id" form="carform">
                <?php foreach ($dropdownArray as $key):?>
                    <option placeholder="rest_id*" id="rest_id" name="rest_id" value="<?=$key['restid']; ?>"> <?= $key['restaurantnavn']; ?> </option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" id="carform">
            <div class="span3"> 
                <div class="input-holder">
                    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="membernumber" name="membernumber" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Medlems. Nr.*" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3"> 
                <div class="input-holder">
                    <input type="text" class="form-input" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Beløb.*" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3"> 
                <div class="input-holder">
                    <input type="submit" value="Godkend">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
    var field1=document.forms["myForm"]["membernumber"].value;
    var field2=document.forms["myForm"]["subtotal"].value;
    var myLength = $("#membernumber").val().length;

    if (field1==null || field1=="")
    {
        alert("something A");
        return false;
    }

    if (myLength < 8 || myLength > 8)
    {
        alert("something B");
        return false;
    }

    if (field2==null || field2=="")
    {
        alert("something C");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("something D");
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the web developer console in your browser of choice? There is most likely an error occurring.

Comment: First things first: indent your code...

Comment: when i just copy and past your code, then the `validateForm` function is called, so there must be an error somewhere else.

Comment: @pickypg: Yes, there is no error according the console

Comment: You could try to set a beakpoint and see what happens

Comment: May i know why you are not using like this document.getElementById('membernumber').value or $('#membernumber').val();

Comment: Did you notice that the `<select>` is outside of your `<form>`? It's probably not the reason, but invalid HTML. Check which DOM is really generated with DOM inspector whether it's the expected one.

Comment: Have you tested it in many browsers ?

Comment: @Bergi, i did notice that. But according to W3, it is the way . http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp

Comment: I would try putting something in the action and renaming the form id so that it is the same as the name attribute.

Comment: @Zaz: Ah, didn't notice you used the [HTML5 `form` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form) - but in your case it would need to be `form="myForm"`. And do not confuse w3schools.com with the W3 organisation, they are not associated with each other!

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rYrcY/

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#carform").on('submit', function(){
        var field1 = document.forms["myForm"]["membernumber"].value;
        var field2 = document.forms["myForm"]["subtotal"].value;
        var myLength = $("#membernumber").val().length;

        if (field1 == null || field1 == "") {
            alert("something A");
            return false;
        }

        if (myLength < 8 || myLength > 8) {
            alert("something B");
            return false;
        }


        if (field2 == null || field2 == "") {
            alert("something C");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("something D");
            return true;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: did it solved your query?

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing it in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4xbU/) and seems to work.

Check if you are adding your script in the `head` of your HTML and that you have the Jquery scripts right before your javascript include.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="yourscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your html code and it DOES read the js function. I doubt there's sth wrong in your php code which break the parse process of browser. Plz check your whole html again and paste it if you need.